# Value gets truncated in oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, plsqldeveloper

In my code I have added logic to add a char value like 'P' to an column in oracle DB. The column type is nvarchar2(1). But while querying the table through plsql developer I am seeing that column as blank, but on changing the column size as 2, I could see the value. What should be the solution if I need to save it like a single char only ?

Comment: Is the length of the column byte based or char based? I wonder if you're trying to store a 2+ byte unicode char in a 1 byte column

Comment: Please, show the output of the below queries: `select *
from nls_database_parameters
where parameter = 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET'

union all

select *
from nls_session_parameters
where parameter = 'NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS'`  and `select dump(your_col_name, 16) from your_table`

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the value as you `SELECT` it:

```sql
SELECT column_name || 'P' AS formatted_column_name
FROM   table_name;
```